# How to automate the naming of a column of several dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Hope you're doing good!

My problem is the following: I have created many dataframes using a loop, and have automatically given them incremental names: `df1, df2` and so on. I would like to do the same with a column of these dataframes: `col1, col2` and so on. I stored the name of the current dataframe in a name `df_name`, and the name of the current new column in a name `col_name`.

I tried to correct the name using rename, colnames, names, or even already creating the dataframe with the correct name.

For example I tried `colnames(eval(df_name)) = c(c("dtt", "cnpj", col_name))`, but I receive this error:

> could not find function "eval<-"

If I try something like `assign(names(eval(df_name))[3], col_name)`, a new variable is created, instead of changing the name of the third column of the dataframe.

I tried to condition the name of this column in the creation of each dataframe, but apparently it's not possible to use `assign` inside of `mutate` (because I use it to create every dataframe).

A piece of my code so far:

```
for(i in 1:k){
  df_name = as.name(paste0("df",i))
  assign(as.character(df_name), df %>% 
           mutate(dtt=dtt-i, n2=n) %>% select(-n))
  col_name = paste0("col",i)
  #rename n2 with col_name
}
```

Only explaining: I am creating a new dataframe for the information of `n2` in `i` days ahead (`dtt` is a date), then I'll join all the dataframes and I'll have the information of `n2` for the original day and `k` days ahead. Maybe there's a simpler way of doing that.

Comment: give an example.  instead of just explaining

Comment: Can you add some more information on your set up? You have a loop, and each iteration of the loop has a `dfX` and a variable for the column being added in that iteration?

Comment: Ok. I just added some more info